# Lambda in C# extension method

Tags: c#, lambda, extension-methods

Suppose I want to write an extension method to dump some data from a `T[,]` to a CSV:

```
public static void WriteCSVData<T>(this T[,] data, StreamWriter sw)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < data.GetLength(0); row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < data.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            string s = data[row, col].ToString();

            if (s.Contains(","))
                sw.Write("\"" + s + "\"");
            else
                sw.Write(s);

            if (col < data.GetLength(1) - 1)
                sw.Write(",");
            else
                sw.WriteLine();
        }
}
```

which I could call with

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("data.csv"))
  myData.WriteCSVData(sw);
```

but suppose `myData` is a `Complex[,]` and I want to write the magnitude of the complex number, not the full value. It would be handy if I could write:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("data.csv"))
  myData.WriteCSVData(sw, d => d.Magnitude);
```

but I'm not sure how to implement that in the extension method or if it's even possible.

Comment: Don't forget to quote any quotes or newlines in your output fields!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write an overload of your existing method like this:

```
public static void WriteCSVData<T, TValue>(this T[,] data, StreamWriter sw, 
    Func<T,TValue> func)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < data.GetLength(0); row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < data.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            string s = func(data[row, col]).ToString();

            if (s.Contains(","))
                sw.Write("\"" + s + "\"");
            else
                sw.Write(s);

            if (col < data.GetLength(1) - 1)
                sw.Write(",");
            else
                sw.WriteLine();
        }
}
```

and use it the way you wanted:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("data.csv"))
    myData.WriteCSVData(sw, d => d.Magnitude);
```

Comment: -1, Your `for` loop version generates a new line for each row, while your LINQ version generates a new line for each element.

Comment: @Gabe you're right. I must have overlooked that it only writes a new line for the last element of a row. removed.

Answer (score 1):

Define a delegate with parameter type **T** and return type **string**. Add a parameter to method WriteCSVData with type the delegate.

```
delegate string ExtractValueDelegate<T>(T obj);

public static void WriteCSVData<T>(this T[,] data,ExtractValueDelegte<T> extractor , StreamWriter sw) { ... }

// calling the method
 myData.WriteCSVData(sw, d => d.Magnitude.ToString());
```

Comment: There is no need for "manual delegates" anymore. .NET has them built in now - `Func<T, string>` in this case...